# Notation used for the equations of the SIR model

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, notation

I am confused about the notation used in the SIR model.

Most of the works found online present the equations of the compartments as following:

$s_{t+1}=s_t-αs_ti_t$

$i_{t+1}=i_t+αs_ti_t-γi_t$

$r_{t+1}=γi_t$

But theoretically these are functions of time so shouldn't they be represented as:

$s(t+1)=s(t)-α·s(t)·i(t)$

$i(t+1)=i(t)+α·s(t)·i(t)-γ·i(t)$

$r(t+1)= r(t)+γi(t)$?

Is it because they are recursive formulas referring to the position in time so the subscript form should be used instead? But then, when I am referring exclusively to the function of susceptibles, infected, or recovered at a particular time, is the $S(t)$, $I(t)$ and $R(t)$ notation correct or should I still employ $S_t$, $I_t$ and $R_t$?

In some pieces of work online these equations are differentiated as $\frac{ds(t)}{dt}$, $\frac{di(t)}{dt}$ and $\frac{dr(t)}{dt}$ but in that case shouldn't the derivatives be $s'(t)$, $i'(t)$ and $r'(t)$? What would be the correct notation for the first derivatives  if  $s_t$, $i_t$ and $r_t$ where the original functions?

Comment: The subscript on $s_{t+1}$ is intended to say $s(t+1)$. Also, $\dfrac{ds}{dt} = s'(t)$ *usually*, although some people prefer $\dot{s}(t)$ since it's a time derivative.

Comment: It is all notation, you can do what you like as long as you adhere to one of the several possible established notational conventions. Argument vs subscript and prime vs Leibniz notation are all established notations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a discrete-time model, where $t$ is an integer, and then it's very common to write $s_t$ instead of $s(t)$ (both are fine).

If you see these equations with derivatives, then you are looking at a continuous-time model instead, and in that case the notation is almost always $s(t)$, except that often one write just $s$ for simplicity. The derivative can be written as $s'$ or $\dot s$ or $ds/dt$, just choose your favourite...